# data-name attribute fetch row details in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Here is a checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" data-name="TWIC Card" name="chkSP" id="chkSP8" value="8">
<label id="lblOut8" for="chkSP8" value="8">TWIC Card</label>
```

In jquery how can i checked true by using the data-name???

I am tried a lot code:

```
$("input[data-name='" + $.trim(SPArray[i]) + "']").prop("checked", "checked");
$("input[data-name='" + $.trim(SPArray[i]) + "']").attr("checked", "checked");
$("input[data-name='" + $.trim(SPArray[i]) + "']").attr('checked', true);
```

these are not working.

Can anyone tell me how can i get the details by data-name??

Important Note:-I want to fetch by only data-name features.

Here is my whole total code:

here is the input type :

```
<div class="check-box"><input type="checkbox" data-name="4' Tarps" name="chkSP" id="chkSP7" value="7"><label id="lblOut7" for="chkSP7" value="7">4' Tarps</label></div>

<div class="check-box"><input type="checkbox" data-name="TWIC Card" name="chkSP" id="chkSP8" value="8"><label id="lblOut8" for="chkSP8" value="8">TWIC Card</label></div>

 var SP="TWIC Card" ;
var SPArray = SP.split(',');
                            var allSelectedSP = "";
for (var i = 0; i < SPArray.length; i++) {
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[data-name='" + SPArray[i].trim() + "']")).forEach(function (input) {
                                            input.checked = true;
                                        });
allSelectedSP += ", " + $.trim(SPArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: try use `console.log($.trim(SPArray[i]))` and make sure it writes `TWIC Card` `$.trim()` might remove the space in TWIC Card

Comment: yes it writes TWIC Card

Comment: What does SPArray contain ?

Comment: Where does `$.trim(SPArray[i])` come from? Maybe I'm looking at this to easy, but `$('[data-name="TWIC Card"]')` should work...

Comment: @LinkinTED I think the OP wants all in an array to be checked

Comment: yes $('[data-name="TWIC Card"]') comes but not working...

Comment: yes here i am checked..

Comment: can anyone give me the solutions??

Comment: /var b = document.querySelectorAll("[data-name="TWIC Card"]"); it returns null

Comment: please someone help me to solve??

Comment: SPArray = ["TWIC Card"]

Comment: We can't give you solutions as what you've shown already works: http://jsfiddle.net/utzvtx5d/, although it should really be `prop('checked', true)`

Comment: Wow, don't spam the comments please, rather add the full code to your question...

Comment: in javascript is there any solutions?How can i get the attribute details by javscript?

Comment: Try `$(document).find("input[data-name='" + $.trim(SPArray[i]) + "']").prop("checked", "checked");`

Comment: still not working

Comment: Any solutions??i have mention the whole code..

Answer (score 2):

In pure Javascript you can use **[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** with the following slector `"input[data-name='" + SPArray[i].trim() + "']"`, it will do the same thing:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[data-name='" + SPArray[i].trim() + "']")).forEach(function(input) {
  input.checked = true;
});
```

```js
var SPArray = ['TWIC Card'];
var i = 0;


Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[data-name='" + SPArray[i].trim() + "']")).forEach(function(input) {
  input.checked = true;
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-name="TWIC Card" name="chkSP" id="chkSP8" value="8">
<label id="lblOut8" for="chkSP8" value="8">TWIC Card</label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" data-name="Tee Card" name="chkSP" id="chkSP4" value="8">
<label id="lblOut4" for="chkSP8" value="4">Tee Card</label>
```

Comment: not working..may be problem to find the document.querySelectorAll it comes null

Comment: In your code you wrote `SP.split(',')` where `SP` is an array, and not a string, it's the cause of the problem, array don't have split method, I think it should be `SP[0].split(',')`

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("input[data-name='" + SPArray[i].trim() + "']") here length comes 0

Comment: so it is not going through foreach loop.

Comment: Maybe you are executing this code before the page is loaded make sure, it's in `$ready()`, and make sure it's in the bottom of your body.